# Why the order of the data returned by the ajax call interface is not correct？

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, linkedhashmap

1. The order of the data returned by the ajax call interface is incorrect. If the key is a string, it is correct, and the key is in a numerical order.
2. The data returned by the postman call interface is correct.

```
{
    "3": "3#",
    "4": "4#",
    "5": "5#",
    "2": "2#",
    "1": "1#"
}
```

3. ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: 'xxx/xxx/xxxx',
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
           console.log(result.data)
      }
   }）
```

1. ajax result

```
{
    1: "1#",
    2: "2#",
    3: "3#",
    4: "4#",
    5: "5#"
}
```

2. The background uses springboot and returns LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backend is returning a JSON object. Values inside a JSON object have no defined order. Thats why they have a key/value pair. You can never assume a special order in a JSON object.

Comment: Why is the data received by postman orderly?